# Efficient algorithm to calculate nonlinear conductivity spectra

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, fourier-transform, non-linear-systems

I'm just thinking about the efficient algorithm to calculate the photovoltaic conductivity
$$
J(0) = \sigma^{(2)}(0, \omega, -\omega)E(\omega)E(-\omega)
$$
in time domain calculation. In the case of linear conductivity, $\sigma^{(1)}(\omega) = J(\omega)/E(\omega)$, we can get this by Fourier transform of the current response to the delta-function-like input in the time domain. But the calculation of nonlinear conductivity requires us to calculate the response to the oscillating external field, changing the frequency of the field.

My question is, is it possible to find this kind of efficient relation in the case of the nonlinear photovoltaic effect? In my intuition, it's quite difficult for the general response function $\sigma^{2)}(\omega_{1} + \omega_{2}, \omega_{1} , \omega_{2})$, but if we restrict it to the DC response, we may find efficient algorithm.